# Access form to use SQL Server query/stored procedure to populate a field

Tags: forms, ms-access, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Microsoft SQL Server database with a table called `tblCABLE` with the following two relevant columns:

```
ID - indentity
CableID - nchar(8) not null
```

I have an `After Insert` trigger on that table that I have written and when all the columns of `tblCABLE` are entered it runs fine on.

I am trying to create a front end form in access for data entry to `tblCABLE` so that the trigger can run on new rows.

My problem is that I want the column of `CableID` to be populated automatically on opening a new record form in Access but do not know how to do this.

I have written some SQL code which will generate the new `CableID` as follows (the problem is how to add this to run on a new record form in Access

```
declare @newcableID nchar(8)
declare @cableIDnum int
declare @maxcableID nchar(8)

set @maxcableID = (select max(cableid) from tblCable)
set @cableIDnum = (convert(int, substring(@maxcableID,3,8)))
set @cableIDnum = @cableIDnum + 1
set @newcableID = (select 'CA' + right('000000' + cast((@cableIDnum) as varchar),6))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok. The database system would be Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please **don't do this**! Using a `SELECT MAX()+1` approach is inherently **bad** and it **will break** under load and produce duplicate values.

Let the SQL Server database handle this by using a column of type `INT IDENTITY` - something like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblCable
(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblCable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
 ...(other columns here).....
)
```

That way, SQL Server guarantees properly handled `ID` values - once you've inserted a new row, the `ID` will be a unique, valid number and you don't have to fiddle and mess around with creating that unique ID yourself.

If you need a column that concatenates the numeric `ID` value with a fixed prefix, use a **computed column**:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblCable
ADD CableID AS 'CA' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) PERSISTED
```

and you're done! Whenever you insert a new row, SQL Server will give you a unique `ID` (e.g. 42), and your `CableID` column will automatically contain `CA000042`

Comment: I thought of this but because I have data to enter already I didn't want to be restricted by the ID field but I have done this the way you mentioned and it works. I will just find somebody to enter the data manually to put the cables in order. Thanks for your help.